# Firebase deploy only uploads 2 files

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I'm able to successful login to firebase and use firebase deploy, but then instead of uploading my simple 6 files web app, it just says "uploading 2 files".

Basically just the default firebase index and error404 files.

What else can I try?

My hosting URL:
https://my-website-73bac.web.app

Firebase deploy only 2 files

[image: Firebase deploy only 2 files]

My public folder has 6 files
[image: My public folder has 6 files]

Comment: Are those images being used in either of the HTML files? I can't find them in the link that you've provided.

Comment: The attached images are a screenshot of my cmd and my "public" folder which contains 6 files to be uploaded to firebase hosting. But then "firebase deploy" says found 2 files in public. As it turns out my hosting link is the default firebase homepage.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the contents of your `firebase.json` config file?